# What Is the Issue Suddently the Database Stopped Sending Emails Out After It is Upgraded from Oracle 10g to 11g R1?

Tags: oracle11g

Hi Oracle Database Gurus,
What is the issue suddently the Database stopped sending Emails out after it is upgraded from Oracle 10g to 11g R1? I double check the email demon on the server it is working fine when I send an email from the linux command line (not through an database procedue). And the smtp_out_server parameter value is the same before and after the upgrade...
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you get any errors?  The first thing that jumps to mind is that 11g introduces more fine-grained permissions for packages like `UTL_MAIL` and `UTL_SMTP` that interact with other servers.  Your DBA would need to [create an appropriate network ACL](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/11g/FineGrainedAccessToNetworkServices_11gR1.php) in order to allow you to access external servers from within your PL/SQL code.

If you don't have sufficient permission, your code should be getting an "ORA-24247: network access denied by access control list (ACL)" error.  Are you getting such an error?  Or is it possible that you have a `WHEN OTHERS` exception handler that is hiding that error from you?

Do you see any rows in `USER_NETWORK_ACL_PRIVILEGES` (or `DBA_NETWORK_ACL_PRIVILEGES` or `ALL_NETWORK_ACL_PRIVILEGES` depending on what user you're logging in as, what user is sending mail, and your privilege level)?  If so, is there a row for your mail server with whatever port range your SMTP server is listening on?

Comment: thx Justin, yes, I think you hit the nail on the head. In order for utl_mail package working in 11g, which require xml db and configure the acl packages. Our db has xml db already, and I have configured the acl packages and in testing currently...